# RPC endpoint list with ncalrpc

Tags: c++, rpc, endpoint

I have one question about RPC endpoints list. I want to get endpoints with ncalrpc protocol sequence (local RPC endpoints) but do this remote! I have IP address of the remote machine in my LAN, and my purpose is list of ncalrpc RPC endpoints. How can I do it?

There aren't any problem with ncacn_np and ncacn_ip_tcp protocol sequences. But if I use ncalrpc, the function `RpcBindingFromStringBinding()` get 1707 error. I know that it is possible, because plugin of Metasploit - endpoint_mapper can does it. But the language of this plugin id Ruby, not C++.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The point of ncalrpc is that you can't use the endpoints remotely.

You could have a remote service that can enumerate ncalrpc endpoints for you, but it won't work externally.